# CheckBoxField in an ASP.Net Dynamic dataset loaded GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, types, dataset

I`m making an ASP.Net webpage, which contains a dynamic gridView.
The user is suppoused to be able to search for a specific row in the gridView by the username;

One of the fields contains a checkbox, and I have problem loading it into the dataset. Here's a part of my code:

```
        DataTable container = new DataTable();
        DataRow convertedForTable = container.NewRow();
        DataSet final = new DataSet(); 
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Username", typeof(string)));
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeJoined", typeof(DateTime)));
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Banned", typeof(CheckBoxField))); // Here the problem starts
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Admin", typeof(CheckBoxField))); // That is also a checkboxField.
        container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Options", typeof(object))); // And that's a GridView edit field. I have no idea what type it is.
        object[] rowArray = new object[myRow.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < myRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            rowArray[i] = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
        convertedForTable.ItemArray = rowArray;
        container.Rows.Add(convertedForTable);
        final.Tables.Add(container); 
        Cache["Users"] = final; // From the cache, the dataset is later loaded & displayed.
```

Anyhow, I get this.

> Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <> in Banned Column.  Expected type is CheckBoxField.

I understand the error, although I have no idea how to fix it. What type should I put in those columns?

Comment: @Mate Tried, got the same message ("Expected type is Boolean")

Comment: @Mate It's a checkbox - The debugger reads `<>`

Comment: @A.Abramov Take a look at my answer and let me know if you resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are going to store something except `CheckBoxField` to `Banned` column
make sure that items type are the same

you can do something like this:

```
container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Username", typeof(string)));
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeJoined", typeof(DateTime)));
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Banned", typeof(bool))); 
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Admin", typeof(bool))); 
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Options", typeof(object))); 
    object[] rowArray = new object[6];
    rowArray[0] = "Item 0" ;
    rowArray[1] = DateTime.Now ;
    rowArray[2] = "Item 2" ;
    rowArray[3] = true;
    rowArray[4] = false;
    rowArray[5] = "object";
```

If you want to add `CheckBox` to item 3 and 4 you should do something like this:

```
container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Banned", typeof(CheckBox)));
    container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Admin", typeof(CheckBox)));  
    rowArray[3] = new CheckBox()
        {
            ID = "newID3",
            Checked = true// Or your condition based on myRow.Cells[3].Text
        };
    rowArray[4] = new CheckBox()
    {
        ID = "newID4",
        Checked = true// Or your condition based on myRow.Cells[3].Text
    };
```

this is not different you can also add `CheckBoxField` to `Banned` and `Admin` column.

Hope will help.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it as soon as I get to my code. How do I put a gridView "Edit" button (the one that triggers an event) in a cell?

Comment: @A.Abramov Good, there are several ways to add edit button e.g. [TemplateField](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx) or built in [Edit Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx).

Comment: I already have one. My question is, If I want to include that button in the dataset, How can I do that?

Comment: You can not add `Button` to `DataTable` , DataTable DataType property only support primitive .NET Framework data types take a look at [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: how would you advice solving it then?

Comment: @A.Abramov for `bool` you just use `typeof(bool)`, and ?